# Me and a friend are making a text adventure game, but when we ge to the Pay or Steal part, it doesnt show up. Any ideas?

Tags: python

```
while True:
 if merchant == "axe":
   p_or_s = input(f'Good choice! That will be 50 gold.\n[Pay]\n[Steal]\n').lower()
   break
  if p_or_s == "pay":
   pay = input('Thank you sir/madam, please come again anytime!').lower()
   bal -= 50
   break
  if p_or_s == "steal":
   steal = input('THIEF COME BACK HERE').lower()
   break
  else:
    print("That is not a valid option.")
```

This is the section that's giving us trouble. It isn't showing the Steal or Pay options in the console, and we've been scratching out heads about it all day. We are pretty new, so this is probably a pretty obvious answer, but we figured we'd ask

Comment: Look at the section where you are setting `p_or_s`, what happens when you call `break` inside a while loop?

Comment: @scrappedcola It stops the loop from repeating

Comment: It also stops the rest of the loop from running.

Comment: So if you break after setting `p_or_s`, you break out of the loop before checking `if p_or_s == ...`

Comment: @Barmar Oh my god I'm kinda dumb. Thank you

Comment: Please use the recommended 4 spaces of indentation. It's hard to tell the structure with just 1 space.

Comment: @Barmar My bad, thanks